# Excel : Sum of Unique values of corresponding column in the filter - Multiple columns in between

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to have Sum of values in [G] against DISTINCT values of corresponding column [C] in the filter i.e. B

I tried

```
SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(G:G, (C:C)*(B:B=I2)))
```

also tried

```
SUM(IF(Frequency)))
```

[image]

Comment: Could these numbers in population differ between areas even when columns B:C is the same to any of the rows above it? If not, then alternatively to the answer below you could use `=SUM(TAKE(UNIQUE(FILTER(HSTACK(B:C,G:G),B:B=I2)),,-1))`. Almost the same thing and not worth another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is where using CHOOSECOL will help but you need to use that in the FILTER:

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(A:G,2,3,7),B:B=I2)),0,3))
```

Now only the three columns are passed to the FILTER output and only those three columns are looked at for the UNIQUE.